# EF6 with Sqlite one-to-many relationship failing on Unique Constraint

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I'm running into an issue when inserting entities with one-to-many relationships into an SQLite database using Entity Framework 6. Let's consider this example:

**Model**

```
public class Box {
    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}

public class Item {
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Box Box { get; set; }
}
```

**Insertion**

```
Box box = new Box(){BoxId = 1};
Item item = new Item(){ItemId = 1, Box = box};
using (var db = new MyDbContext()) {
    db.Boxes.Add(box);
    db.SaveChanges();
    db.Items.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

*This snippet works.*

```
Box box = new Box(){BoxId = 1};
Item item = new Item(){ItemId = 1, Box = box};
using (var db = new MyDbContext()) {
    db.Boxes.Add(box);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
using (var db = new MyDbContext()) {
    db.Items.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

*This snippet doesn't work, throws an Exception with message UNIQUE constraint failed*

I understand why it doesn't work, but I can't figure out a way to make it work. Using the same context is not an option, because the application could be restarted between the creation of the Box and the addition of an Item. I found an answer to the same question but using EF core instead of EF6 ([right there (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500403/ef-core-sqlite-one-to-many-relationship-failing-on-unique-index-constraint)) but I can't access the `TrackGraph` property of the `ChangeTracker` with EF6.

I would also need to have a fully generic way of solving this issue, because I could possibly have other objects in my Boxes than Items.

Comment: Just wrap in try-catch.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov and then what? I need the solution to be generic, I can't be doing special cases in a catch.

Comment: If exception thrown then do nothing. Item already added in previous using block.

Comment: No it wasn't, only box was added in the first using block. I might have initialized item after the first using block, the result would be the same.

Comment: Item was added via navigation property. This is why you get an exception.

Comment: And how do I reference a box from an item without getting exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured a way.

Before calling `db.SaveChanges()` I execute this code, where entities is the list of entities I just added to the DbContext. This way only entities that I explicitly wanted to add are added, other related entities are not added, and thus I don't run into Unique constraint failed because DbContext is not recreating related entities.

```
db.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList().ForEach(dbe => {
    if (!entities.Contains(dbe.Entity)) {
        dbe.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
});
```